# Using AWK to list several columns from a db queried list when some fields are blank?

Tags: shell, awk

I am trying to selectively display several columns from a db table(see sample below) using awk. While not all the fields are populated, I still need to return a blank field to represent it.

```
--------- -------------------------- ------------ ------
000       0000000000198012           702          29
000       0000000000198013                        29
000                                  702          29
000       0000000000198015           702          03
055       0000000000000001           702
```

This is what I'm using:

```
select * from db| awk '{print $1,$3,$4}'
```

but in the rows where there is a blank field, awk is skipping over those fields and displaying the result from the next populated field. How do I display the results accurately?

-Thanks!

Comment: Doesn't really answer your question directly but its a really good thread. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2902462/extract-lines-when-column-k-is-empty-with-awk-perl Also what you want done is pretty hard to do unless you have some method of identifying that one or more fields are empty in a line. Check out that thread.

Comment: Workable solutions below are good. But can't  you specify a FieldSep for your SQL output? Then you can just check `if ($2=="") ...`. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks Florin, that was a good link but you are correct, its not quite what I'm after.

Comment: Good point shelter, I'll try to see if I can do that in DB2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the columns have a consistent/static width, and the spacing is handled with ' ' characters, not tabs (meaning every line is the same length, regardless of missing fields), you could use `cut` with an appropriate list of field start/stop positions.

Comment: I'm trying this method, but so far have been getting syntax errors and "stty: setattr: There is an input or output error."

The command I'm using from within a shell script is:
    <my sql query> |awk 'BEGIN -v FIELDWIDTHS="9 48 12 6 24 3 30 6" {print $7}'

Comment: The `-v` option doesn't belong in the program argument. Either use `awk -v FIELDWIDTHS="..." '{print $7}'` or `awk 'BEGIN{FIELDWIDTHS="..."}{print $7}'`.

Comment: I'm sorry, I meant to reply to slitvinov's post. Thank you for looking at this too! You guys are all very helpful!

Comment: Due to the fact that I am unable to utilize 'gawk', 'cut' was next and it worked beautifully! Here is my sample code:
myquery | cut -c 1-9,11-48,60-68,112-142,143-159 --output-delimiter=";"

My only question is, in regards to the character ranges in "cut -c", I am manually listing each field width. Is there a better way to do this? For instance, I have the schema info for this table. If I put the 'column length' into a flat file and use that as a lookup table to feed the "cut -c" character length, is that the best way to go about this? @twalberg

Comment: @fembot I am not aware of any version of `cut` that has capabilities like that (which does not mean one might not exist). You could however, put the string "1-9,...143-159" in a file, say `fields.txt`, and then do `myquery | cut -c \`cat fields.txt\`` (alternatively, depending on which shell you use, `cut -c $(<fields.txt)`).

Comment: Sorry to keep coming back to this, but it looks like the target system does not have the GNU version of "cut". Hence, I cannot use the output-delimiter option. I can use "sed" to add a delimiter, however I am again running into the issue where if a field is blank in Column N, then it will just pull the field from Column N+1. Is there a way to delimit **empty** fields as (field2; ;field4)?

Comment: Hmmm... Might be difficult with a primitive `cut`. Maybe another idea using `awk` without the extensions: `awk '{printf "%s;%s;%s\n",substr($0, 1, 9),substr($0,11,38),substr($0,60,9);}'` might serve - obviously needs to be extended to handle the list of fields you want, and it will be ugly, but it should work since `substr` should be in even non-GNU `awk` versions...

Comment: In order to collapse the "empty" fields, something like `awk {x=substr($0,1,9);gsub("^ +$","",x);/*repeat for all fields*/printf("%s;...\n",x,...);}` would work, but that's getting even uglier, and you'd be better writing the `awk` program to a file and using the `awk -f foo.awk` syntax mentioned elsewhere...

Comment: Awesome! This worked, on the target machine too! You are right, it's a bit ugly but I think the only way to do this. @twalberg let me know where should I send the fruit basket.

Answer (score 3):

`gawk` has  FIELDWIDTHS
http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Constant-Size.html
Usage:
`command | awk -f foo.awk`

**foo.awk**

```
NR==1 {
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
      FIELDWIDTHS = FIELDWIDTHS " " length($(i))+1
    }
}

NR>1 {
    print $1, $3, $4
}
```

Comment: sorry this is somewhat of a basic question, but if I am piping the sql query to your above statement on a single CLI, should I preface that with an AWK? like <my query> | awk NR==1 {.... ?

Comment: Just a quick update, in case anyone else searching for a similar solution, FIELDWIDTHS worked for me, however due to our server build standards 'gawk' is not available on the target servers. So I ended up using 'cut' instead (see next answer). But here is my working, but very basic, code:  query | awk 'BEGIN{FIELDWIDTHS="9 1 48 1 12 1 6 1 24 1 3"} OFS=";" {print$1,$3,$5,$7}'